# Going back from a user control

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app.

I have a page: PageOne or Main page.

PageOne has an hidden user control, UC1. This UC1 is shown if need it.
UC1 has a listbox with several choices. When user select a choice, UC1 will show another user control, UC2. In other words, UC1 has a hidden UC2 control.

I want, from UC2, hide UC2 and UC1 control. How can I do that? Can I use an event listener on UC1 to know when I can hide UC2 and UC1?

Any advice?

Comment: If UC1 hosts UC2 then you won't be able to hide UC1 from UC2.

Comment: @Matt Lacey: I'm trying to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have UC2 send a message back to the page hosting UC1 and then hide UC1 in response to that message.